# jQuery get closest previous element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In this example I have multiple `a` tags. Under the `Structure` where you can see my `unordered list`, that list was generated by a CMS I am using. But this `ul` needs to a dropdown menu of the previous `a`, which in this case is `Structure`.
I am trying to add some classes and attributes to the `structure`, but with the code I am using, it gets all `a` tags elements. But I only need the element before `ul`

```js
$('.custom-dropdown').each(function() {
    if($(this).children('ul').length) {
        $(this).addClass('dropdown');
        $(this).children('a').addClass('dropdown-toggle'); // the problem is here. I have tried closest(), .prev() but I couldn't use it properly to make it work
        $(this).children('a').attr({'role':'button','data-toggle':'dropdown','id':'navbarDropdown2'});
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu custom-dropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   <a href="" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
   <a href="" class="nav-link">Structure</a>
   <ul>
      <li class="first nav-item">
         <a href="" class="nav-link">Organizational Chart</a>
      </li>
      <li class="last nav-item">
         <a href="" class="nav-link">Commissioner</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <a href="" class="nav-link">Mission</a>
   <a href="" class="nav-link">Strategies</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m No it shouldn't be inside `a`. But I tried the code you provided and it works  as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it covered what you needed - added a bit more detail to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the structure, to find all the `<a>` tags with a corresponding `ul` as the next sibling, you can use:

```
$(this).find('ul>li>a').closest("ul").prev("a")
```

which will find, given `this==.custom-dropdown`, any `ul` (at any level) that has an `li` and `a` as direct descendants, then using `.closest` to go back to that `ul` with `.prev` to get the corresponding `a` that matches.

Using `.prev(selector)` will select the previous only if it matches the selector, it's the same as `.prev().filter(selector)` - it's not the same as `.prevAll().first()` (or is that .last, either way).

Example snippet with added .hide just to demo it working - this would normally be handled by adding the drop down classes/attributes.

```js
$(".custom-dropdown").find('ul>li>a').closest("ul").hide().prev("a").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-menu custom-dropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
  <a href="" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
  <a href="" class="nav-link">Structure</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="first nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Organizational Chart</a>
    </li>
    <li class="last nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Commissioner</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="" class="nav-link">Mission</a>
  <a href="" class="nav-link">Strategies</a>
</div>
```